# Router and IP Scanner shows different number of devices

Tags: networking, mac, osx-mavericks

I logged into my router and looked at the stats. It has 9 devices.

I used a Mac app (IP Scanner) to scan available devices, I only see 4.

What does this mean? 5 devices are blocking the IP Scanner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are those (mostly) wifi-connected devices?

The router shows existing leases, in its DHCP table. When a pc disconnects, its lease of an IP address does not automatically expire, because the router has no way to know whether the device has moved away, or is just sleeping/hybernating. Thus the lease survives the leasee.

The scanner shows the pcs which reply to its probes. This may certainly omit hiding devices, but it is difficult to be completely invisible to a good scanner, if not outright impossible. So the scanner detects the devices which are present at any given moment.

This number may differ from the number of devices reported by the router also for another reason: static IP devices do not appear in the list of DHCP leases on your router. They do appear in the list of known clients, and this in turn differs from that of leasees because of the possible presence of static IP devices. Again, scanner outputs include static IP devices, unless they are truly, truly stealthy.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the ARP table on the router.